# What is the best way to alter menu permission?

Tags: permissions, menu

I need different access argument for "civicrm/group/add" 
For now I found only 2 options: alter Group.xml or with hook_civicrm_xmlMenu
unset Group.xml and use my own file to defined menus. 
But it would be nice just to use some hook to alter access arguments. Is there anything like that?

Answer (score 1):

Could [hook_civicrm_alterMenu](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterMenu/) be what you need?